# Working with VSS and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, visual-sourcesafe, vcs-checkout

i created a project to search textfiles with lucene.net. [asp.net/vs08]
these textfiles are in a VSS server.

i'm looking for a way how to "check out" or "copy" a Document (later on the whole vss structure with documents) and put it on in a folder on an IIS Server.

how can i do that?

--> copy a document from vss TO Folder on IIS Server   [ Later all documents in the original strucutre]

bye the way, its important that the documents keep their original creationdate.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by VSS you mean Visual Source Safe, then you would basically need to use its API to get the documents. I.e. a little short of writing a client for it.

Here's an article with info where you can find the VSS API:
http://weblogs.asp.net/nilotpal/archive/2006/04/27/444199.aspx

Comment: yes i mean visual source safe,
and where from do i get the api?
i've found http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.visualstudio.sourcesafe.interop%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: It comes with Visual Studio - look at the link I provided.